# Attempting to call ivregress command within a program fails with an error message

Tags: stata

I have been running an analysis with the command `ivregress`, for instance

```
(...)
ivregress 2sls y1 x1 x2 (y2 = z1 z2)
```

which works correctly.

But the same instruction put inside a program, for instance:

```
 program test
 (...)
 ivregress 2sls y1 x1 x2 (y2 = z1 z2)
 end
 test
```

gives an error message `__00009E not found` when executing the program. After that it is necessary to clear everything to have `ivregress` work at all even outside of a program.

I have made several tests, and the problem seems due specifically to `ivregress` being called from a program.

Other commands, such as `regress y1 x1 x2`, work fine whether from inside a program or outside.

I need to run `ivregress` command from within a program because I want to do a Monte Carlo simulation.

I have not found any information online about this problem, whether it's a problem with the `ivregress` command, or whether there are limitations as to which commands can be called from a program...

Has anyone an explanation or a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by renaming the program as mytest for instance. "test" is a command in Stata and this was probably the issue. It doesn't explain why it did work when "regress" command was called from the program.

Comment: I think it does. When you run `test` without arguments it tries to rerun the last `test` (official) command. In your case the previous `test` is remembered but it used temporary variables that no longer exist, so no go. Stata never even tries to run your program at all and the error has nothing to do with what is inside. That is my interpretation. In summary, your problem is all about using a name for a program which is that of an existing command (which will always be tried first) and nothing at all to do with your contents of your program, including the fact that it uses `ivregress`.

Comment: To test further, `set trace on` and see what happens.

Comment: Names beginning with double underscores are temporary names.